# Does 肉 only mean non-preserved meats?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Recently I read the following exchange:

```
A: 何か食べたい？
B: お肉
A: 肉か
朝から肉ねえ。
俺は冷蔵庫を物色する。
案の定肉は切らしていた
A: 昨晩、使い切ったからな。ソーセージもベーコンもハムすら無い
B: お肉無い？
A: ああ。無い。肉どころかハムやソーセージなどの燻製ものすら無い
```

Judging from it, there seems to be a large distinction drawn between 肉 and 燻製. Specifically, I'm wondering if in Japanese it's always the case that when you say `肉を食べたい` you mean that you want to eat non-preserved meats.

Answer (score 2):

You encountered two contextual meanings of 肉. It is fairly common in most languages to use the same word for a concept as well as in a more narrow sense for a specific object.

Compare to English where meat in "a piece of meat" is not the same as "being a meat eater". Japanese distinguishes between a specific object and general category only by context only, not by grammatical construction, so this kind of confusion is common.

1. 肉を食べたい . Meat in the general sense. Including all meat products like sausages and smoked meat. In this statement meat includes preserved meat.
2. 冷蔵庫に肉がある. A specific piece of raw meat in your fridge.

Comment: でも「お肉が食べたい！」って言ってる人にウインナー出したらたぶん怒られますよね・・・鶏のから揚げ出しても怒る人いそう・・「今日の晩ご飯はお肉よ！」とか言ってウインナーとかベーコンってことはないですし。。

Comment: @Chocolate 「何でもいいからお肉が食べたい」に対して「ベーコンならあるけど？」と返して怒る人はいないと思うので、それこそ「文脈による」というこの回答の趣旨でいいのかなーと

Comment: @naruto はい、「文脈による」ってところは賛成です。

Answer (score 0):

`肉` in response to `何か食べたい?` "do you want to eat anything?" refers to a kind of dish. I think it's the same in English. "What's the dinner, honey? Chicken" refers to a dish where a chicken meat is a center piece.

So the first three lines set the scene where readers mentally picture a meat dish, which is unusual choice for a breakfast and thus implies a big appetite. But then next, it is revealed that there's no meat piece that's suitable for that, which leads to `肉どころかハムやソーセージなどの燻製ものすら無い`

This means not only there's no meat in the fridge that can be used as the center piece of a dish that meets the implied appetite, but there are also no ham, bacon, nor sausages, which are common ingredients of a breakfast and thus could have been an answer that somewhat meets the ask, if not very well.

So all in all, I don't read that there is a distinction between `肉` and `燻製`. Rather, the distinction is made between a main piece of a meat dish that's unusual for breakfast, vs the kind of side meat thingy that commonly shows up in breakfast.